# Confirmation of Kubernetes Rate Limiting

Tags: java, kubernetes

If I use k8s as the container platform and set resources.limits.cpu:12 in the YAML file with other defaults, does it mean that CPU throttling will occur when the processing time of the interface exceeds 12*100ms=1.2s?

I found that CPU usage is only around 80% by checking the CPU monitoring. However, I suspect that the CPU monitoring granularity is only at the second level.

Comment: No.  The CPU resource limit is in CPUs.  If you set the limit to 12, that tries to limit the container to 12 CPUs.  If you want half a CPU, you specify `0.5` or `500m`.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-units-in-kubernetes

Comment: Also note that many applications will be bound by database I/O, disk I/O, calls to other services, &c. and not local in-process CPU time.  In the title you mention "rate limiting", it's likely the practical maximum number of concurrent connections will be very different from the CPU limit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.